# E34 BMW V8: unusual CAMshaft sensor signal voltage from ECU

Tags: bmw, electronic-control-module, obd-i, camshaft-position-sensor

My BMW is an E34 with an M60 engine (OBDI) and one morning started idling and running poorly enough to not be drivable. Unplugging the **cam**shaft sensor with the engine running made no change to the way the engine idled (as it should) so I replaced it with a new one and it didn't fix the condition.

Armed with wiring diagrams and a multi-meter I discovered that the **cam**shaft sensor wasn't getting the expected 5 volts from the ecu, but rather starting at about 2.5 volts and steadily dropping towards 0 the longer I held the multi-meter leads on the harness socket.

The **crank**shaft sensor, which I believe is essentially the same sensor, holds steady at just under 5 volts at the harness socket. Both sensors have three wires, one signal wire from the ecu, one ground from the ecu, and one shield ground. The shield ground from both sensors go to the same ground location on the body.

I've inspected the engine harness thoroughly and checked for continuity with the meter and everything looks fine. This led me to suspect that the ecu was bad so I swapped in a junkyard ecu and nothing changed.

I'm perplexed by the dropping ecu signal voltage, hoping someone out there can help...

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
I was doing some reading, the sensors on this car are specifically the inductive type vs hall effect type that came on the M62 engine on later models. Based on what I was reading this type of sensor makes it's own voltage. In that case it makes no sense to me that there would be any voltage coming from the ecu on that wire.

I used a PicoScope to read the output from the unplugged end of the **cam**shaft sensor with the engine cranking:

[image: Oscilloscope reading of **cam**shaft sensor]

I wanted to check that there wasn't a mechanical timing issue and the pulses look normal. Though I was expecting 2 volts at the peaks but got 5 volts instead.

Comment: There is a high joint in the 5v cam sensor wire. Usually this 5v line is shared by other sensors on the engine harness, so the problem is between the cam sensor and where the 5v wire joins the others.

Comment: In this case the ecu has specific 5v pins for both sensors. Are you saying that somewhere in the harness these two merge?

Comment: Not sure about BMW but other manufacturers share the 5v line for engine sensors. What year BMW?

Comment: 1994. It doesn't look like they wires merge anywhere on the harness, the 5v line to the cam and crank sensors are different colors.

Comment: No trying to be smart, but have you tried completing rest of diagnosis for original symptoms?   There are many common reasons in BMWs before diagnosing sensors data stream.   Cracked hoses, bad injectors, intake leaks, etc, etc

Comment: I was thinking of testing for fuel pressure next as the most recent thing I did to the car was install a new fuel pump, but pretty much everything on the car has been addressed in the last couple years like new intake gaskets and injectors, ect. I'm focused on the CPS because there is zero change in idle when you unplug it. Which shouldn't be the case even if there are other issues?